Show function help in quarto book
I want to show the help page of an R function (e.g., help(mean)) in a Quarto book. I use a code chunk like:
#| label: show-help
#| echo: true
help(mean)

All I got in the rendered document is the command help(mean), with no output. I suspect this is because in Rstudio the help is shown by default in the Help pane, but I don'know how to redirect it to the standard output.
